# how install specific package on sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I don't find in packager controller (cmd + install package => tag) the tag plug-in: https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag

how can I install and use it where not in official list?

thx

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Package Control page for `Tag`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Tag), you'll see that it is only supported for Sublime Text 3. The [readme](https://github.com/SublimeText/Tag/blob/st3/readme.md) on Github also indicates this.

I highly recommend [installing ST3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3), as it has many new features not found in ST2, including support for greater plugin functionality. While many plugins still support both 2 and 3, more are moving to 3 only, including this one.

Comment: i don't see particular great feature added in ST3, and we have to pay... thx for anwser, have you another plugin to auto close html tag for ST2?

Comment: @Matrix - if you already have a license for ST2, you can use the beta versions of ST3 up until 3.0 is released (which won't be any time soon, if you ask me). You can also use the [dev builds](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev). If you don't have an ST2 license, you can still use the public beta versions of ST3 for free. (see my link above). As far as other plugins, you might want to check out [`Emmet`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet) if you haven't already. You can also make your own [`.sublime-completions`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/completions.html) file.